# .NET Core 2.2 web app crashes if unit test projects have reference to Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, mstest

I know how weird this sounds.

If I create a brand new .NET 2.2 (netcoreapp2.2) web application, in a solution that also contains a MSTest project (which automatically requires the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk nuget), then when I deploy the project to a Windows 2012 R2 server, the web app will crash with a generic StackOverflow exception. But if I remove the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk reference from the Unit Test projects and deploy again, then the Web application runs fine.

I know - why am I deploying the unit test libraries with the web application.  But regardless, the above statement is still true. For fun, I deleted the unit test libraries off of the hosting server, and the web applicaiton still crashed.

When I say the crash, I mean, I ran dotnet.exe ./NameOfMyWebLibrary.dll and I immediately got a StackOverflow exception. But, again, if I remove Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk from the unit tests projects that are also in the same solution as the web application, and re-deploy, then the application runs fine.

What gives?

Comment: What's the stack trace?